# Why does WP theme not look like promoted?

Tags: themes

I am searching for a WP template on https://wordpress.org/themes/

There I see for example "Kadence":

[image]

I would like to preview it, so I click "More Info" (which appears when I hover the mouse over it).

This takes me to this page:

https://wordpress.org/themes/kadence/

However, this page does not look like the preview.

What do I need to do to view the preview as it was shown?

[image]

Comment: I think the first thing is just an image the theme developers decide on. In theory it could be something completely different than is possible - though that is probably not desired. If you contact the theme authors, they should be able to resolve this and tell you what elements they used to create that look

Comment: Looking at their website they seem to have documentation for most things, try starting there. I also found this https://www.kadencewp.com/wordpress-solutions/get-started-free/, look around their website, you might find something you're missing

Comment: Keep in mind this is a developers stack, not an end user stack, it's expected you know basic programming, if you don't then you may not understand the answers you receive. For general questions about wordpress.org itself you should go to wordpress.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same content and settings the author used to take the thumbnail, theme authors have no control over the content used in the theme preview on .org so the preview rarely shows what the theme is fully capable of.

If the difference is more extreme and it's not possible to install and configure the theme to look that way you should take it up at wordpress.org in their themes support forum.

Comment: Thank you, this is really good to know.